# Cocos2d: Touch handling changing coordinate system

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have this layer that called Gameplay layer that itself is the handler of the Tilemap in game, and to this layer I add the player and add the player to the controlLayer so the player class can be controlled by the player. Then I add the controlLayer as child of this class (Gameplay layer) the problem is now that the coordinates for the touches (ccTouchesBegan...) now becomes in the same coordinates as the tileMap width and height. But I want the controlLayer to be independent and have the normal 480x320 coordinates, how can I fix this?

```
    controlLayer = [[DigGameControlLayer alloc]initWithObjectForPlayerControl:player];
    [self addChild:controlLayer];


- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
  for (UITouch *t in touches) {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];
```

Comment: use "convertToNodeSpace"

Comment: I am using convertToTouchToNodeSpace, and it gives me the width and height of the tilemap

Comment: could you post how are you using the convertToTouchToNodeSpace please

Comment: Filoo: - See update to post

Answer (score 1):

I´m gonna answer my own question, using the LocationInView of the touch´s own view works well enough

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *t in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [t locationInView:t.view];
```

Comment: if you're working with cocos2d what you wrote isn't right, you have to convert your CGPoint coordinates into GL coordinates like this touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];

Comment: Filoo: but it works I just want to know if users touch the left or right side or screen. I can´t see any reason to change it?

Comment: of course if you just need to know if the user has pressed the left or right side of the iphone you can do so, I would remind you, however, that if you consider x/y from the view their 0 start at the upper left of the screen while in cocos2d at the bottom left of the screen

Comment: I usuall use half coordinates. `touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation]; touchLocation = ccp(touchLocation.x / 2, touchLocation.y);` Half coordinates can be used for `CCNode.position`.